# Log4Net add prefix to attributes of messegeobject

Tags: c#, json, log4net

I'm trying to log some values in JSON format using log4net.

Following is my log4net config

```
<appender name="DataDeleteAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
       <file value="c:\\deltanetscratch\\splunk\\DataDelete" />
       <appendToFile value="true" />
       <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
       <rollingStyle value="Date" />
       <datePattern value="'.'yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
       <staticLogFileName value="false" />
       <layout type="log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json">
          <decorator type="log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesFlatDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json" />
          <default />
          <remove value="message" />
          <remove value="appname" />
          <remove value="ndc" />
          <remove value="logger" />
          <remove value="thread" />
          <member value="M:messageobject" />
       </layout>
    </appender>

  <logger name="DataDelete">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="DataDeleteAppender"/>
  </logger>
```

Following is my c# code

```
    _Log.Info(new
    {
    EndTime = DateTime.Now,
    IsClientConnected = HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected,
    batchSize = BatchSize,
    searchStartDate = StartDate,
    searchEndDate = EndDate,
    emails = Emails,
    ActionType = "Queue Course",
    RowsAffected = HttpContext.Current.Items[ROW_COUNTER] == null ? "0" : HttpContext.Current.Items[ROW_COUNTER].ToString()
    });
```

And following is my output. See all attributes get M. prefix here. I want to remove the prefix and get the attribute as it is.

```
{  
   "date":"2017-05-26T15:34:24.7920436+05:30",
   "level":"INFO",
   "M.EndTime":"2017-05-26T15:34:24.7920436+05:30",
   "M.IsClientConnected":true,
   "M.batchSize":2,
   "M.searchStartDate":"2000-04-30T00:00:00.0000000",
   "M.searchEndDate":"2008-04-30T00:00:00.0000000",
   "M.emails":"lec@intl.com",
   "M.ActionType":"Queue Course",
   "M.RowsAffected":"0"
}
```

I'm expecting an output like following.

```
{  
   "date":"2017-05-26T15:34:24.7920436+05:30",
   "level":"INFO",
   "EndTime":"2017-05-26T15:34:24.7920436+05:30",
   "IsClientConnected":true,
   "batchSize":2,
   "searchStartDate":"2000-04-30T00:00:00.0000000",
   "searchEndDate":"2008-04-30T00:00:00.0000000",
   "emails":"lec@intl.com",
   "ActionType":"Queue Course",
   "RowsAffected":"0"
}
```

Can you please how to achieve this output?

Comment: Do you think it could be related to this line in your config? `<member value="M:messageobject" />`

Answer (score 0):

That should be fairly straightforward. Replace:

```
<decorator type="log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesFlatDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json" />
```

with

```
<decorator type="log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json" />
```

The `StandardTypesFlatDecorator` makes the object graph flat, prepending the member path as a prefix.

With `StandardTypesDecorator`, you'll get your messageobject nested inside the logevent object.

If that's still not good enough, then I suggest two options:

1) Implement your own decorator - see the source of the [StandardTypesDecorator](https://github.com/BrightOpen/log4net.Ext.Json/blob/master/log4net.Ext.Json/Layout/Decorators/StandardTypesDecorator.cs) - you can override the `Standardize()` method to merge the LogEvent members with the custom object members.

2) Make use of [NXLog](https://nxlog.co/) or [LogStash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) to rewrite the log. NXlog requires the flat format.